# Clarification about a basic proposition about measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I am making my way through "Linear Functional Analysis" by Bryan P.Rynne and Martin A.Youngson (second edition).

Given a measure space $(X,\Sigma ,\mu )$ we define a function $f$ to be measurable if  for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ then $\{x\in X : f(x) > \alpha \} \in \Sigma$

There is a small proposition that states (with $\bar{\mathbb{R}} =\mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty,\infty \}$)

If $f:X\rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}$  is measurable then the functions $|f|:X\rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ and $f^{\pm}:X\rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}$  defined by $$|f|(x)=|f(x)|, f^{\pm}(x)=\max{\{\pm f(x),0\}}$$

Are measurable.

I am a little confused as to what's the difference here is between these functions? The definition relies on $f(x)$ being comparable to $\alpha$ so we aren't dealing with complex functions. Doesn't this make $|f|=f^{\pm}$ ?

(Page 24 btw)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not defining a single function $f^{\pm}$ but two functions $f^+$ and $f^-$, where $f^+(x) = \max(f(x),0)$ and $f^-(x) = \max(-f(x),0)$.

Comment: Ah, I should of really noticed that as a possibility. How embarrassingly obvious. Thankyou